# "No space left" error installing Gitlab in Ubuntu Server

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-server, gitlab, resizing

I'm trying to install **gitlab** in **Ubuntu Server**. This server has been created in VirtualBox, at the beginning it only had 10GB abailable, but after getting this error I resized the memory up to 25 GB.

The way I updated the memory of the virtualbox was this:

1. Close the machine.
2. Clone the machine (in case something went wrong).
3. Open the **cmd**.
4. `cd Program files/Oracle/Virtualbox`
5. `vboxmanage modifyhd "C:\path\to\UbuntuServer.vdi" --resize 25000`

These are the steps I've followed to install gitlab:

1. `sudo -i` (to enter root mode, later on for the curl request is necesary)
2. `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
3. `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https gnupg2 curl -y`
4. `sudo curl -sL https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/gpgkey | apt-key add -`
5. `nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gitlab.list` (we add the following lines)

   ```
   deb https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ bionic main
   deb-src https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu/ bionic main
   ```
6. `sudo apt-get update -y`

Now appeares the problem:

7. `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce -y`

I would add the complete log after executing this command and I'd also add it in text mode so you could copy it, but I don't know why I can't copy anything from the server so I'd add an image and written by hand the most important things (the log is in spanish but I'll translate it i case someone doesn't know spanish).

[image: Error log]

What we can see in the log:

```
Downloaded 1.311 MB in 43s
Selecting the package ncurses-term previosly not selected.
(Reading database... 75559 files or directories installed at the moment.)
Prepared to unpack .../ncurses-term_6.2-0ubuntu2.1_all.deb ...

...

Unpacking gitlab-ce (16.1.2-ce.0) ...
dpkg: error processing file /var/cache/apt/archives/gitlab-ce_16.1.2-ce.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
could not copy the data extracted from './opt/gitlab/embedded/service/mattermost/prepackaged_plugins/mattermost-plugin-jira-v3.2.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz'
to '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/mattermost/prepackaged_plugins/mattermost_`plugin-jira-v3.2.2-linux-amd64.tar.gz.dpkg-new':
failed to write (No space left on device)
An <<aport>> report was not written because the error message indicates that the error is disk full

pkg-deb: error: the copied subprocess was terminated by the signal (Broken pipe)
```

Is there any problem in the resize?
Should I change something for this to work?
How can I know how much space is free?

**EDIT**

I installed GParted, as mentioned in one of the answers.

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

When executing sudo gparted to use the gparted "terminal" I got thhis message:
[image: Gtk-Warning]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you resize your VM filesystem after `vboxmanage modifyhd`? If not, the simplest way is to download [GParted](https://gparted.org/), boot the VM from the ISO and resize your filesystem.

Comment: No, I didn't resize the VM filesystem after modifying the hd. How do I do that, don't know how GParted works.

Comment: Then that's what is missing :) GParted provides a convenient GUI, here's an explanation: https://dev.to/rishiabee/how-to-expand-a-linux-partition-using-gparted-31c3

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try installing gparted.

Comment: I edited the question with the error I get with Gparted. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Just boot the VM from the GParted ISO instead of the installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know how much space is free?

`df -h`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1201935)

Comment: Lovely, but before edits, the only question in the post was: `How can I know how much space is free?`. This answers it.

Comment: Even if it was, it's a single command with 0 explantation - not really how you should answer here.

Comment: Again, lovely, but your comment says: `This does not provide an answer to the question.`. It does, unequivocally. It's a bit short, sure, but it's an answer all the same. Feel free to downvote, but saying it's not an answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: That's from a review as you can see and the part about not answering current main question from the title is still right. As for multiple questions - they will result likely in the whole post being closed for lack of focus.